# Debug a process started by the current project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

My Visual studio solution contains two C++ console projects, 'A' and 'B', where 'A' programmatically starts B (using CreateProcess()).

If I start stepping through 'A' after the point where 'B' has been created, how can I have breakpoints in the 'B' project be detected and stopped at?

Currently I just stick a "DebugBreak()" at specific points in 'B', but this is rather annoying as it usually takes a while for that window to pop up that allows you to debug the app with a VS instance, and often it won't show up the current instance, so I have to start another that takes even longer.

I can't use attach to process, as 'B' starts up, does its thing and then closes too quick.

Is there any of marking a project to be automatically attached, enabling me for example to have a breakpoint right at the beginning of main (similar to DebugBreak at the beginning of main)?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: I often use 2010, but can use 2012 if need be

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23526300/how-to-programmatically-start-the-second-project-from-the-startup-project-in-t/32132756#32132756

Answer (score 0):

I found this note on MSDN:

> The debugger does not automatically attach to a child process that is started by a debugged process, even if the child project is in the same solution. To debug a child process:
>
> - Attach to the child process after it has been started.
> - -or-
> - Configure Windows to automatically start the child process in a new instance of the debugger.

The latter of which can apparently be accomplished by some registry meddling:
[Automatically start a process in the debugger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/jj919165.aspx#BKMK_Automatically_start_an_process_in_the_debugger)

Comment: I had seen that, but that really isn't any better than DebugBreak. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

The Visual Studio team has released a Visual Studio extension that allows automatically attaching child processes to the current debugger: [Introducing the Child Process Debugging Power Tool](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/11/24/introducing-the-child-process-debugging-power-tool.aspx).

It is available on the [Gallery](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a1141bff-463f-465f-9b6d-d29b7b503d7a) for Visual Studio 2013 and above.

So you can start your Project B from Project A with `Process.Start` and it will automatically attach the debugger to this second process.