# How to programmatically start the second project from the "StartUp" project in the same C# solution?

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2012, process, visual-studio-debugging

I have C# VS 2012 solution with two projects: ProjectA and ProjectB. Both projects are console applications for the sake of simplicity.

ProjectA needs to be started first so it is set as the "Startup project" for the solution. When I run ProjectA with F5 under debugger there are some operations it needs to performs after which it should start ProjectB **under the same debugger**. So if I set breakpoint in ProjectB first line, debugger should break.

Is there any way I can do this? Currently I use Process.Start("path_to_projectB.exe") but that needs to be replaced with something like "Process.StartUnderSameDebugger("path_to_projectB.exe")". I want to use the same instance of VS debugger that started ProjectA for ProjectB.

Note that I don't want to use "Start multiple projects" option in Visual Studio. If I do this both console apps are started simultaneously (which is unwanted) and under the same debugger (which is wanted). First process must perform some stuff before it can start second process and that's why I can't use this approach.

Also when I later stop debugger both processes (console apps from ProjectA and ProjectB) should be closed.

Comment: Why don't you just run project A so that it performs its preparatory operations, and then manually debug project B?

Comment: Because this solution involves inter-process communication. Basically ProjectA is a watchdog for the ProjectB, they are not independent. In development I need both projects to run under same debugger but ProjectA should be the one to start ProjectB.

Comment: In ProjectB have a Console.ReadLine() or something similar at the start.  When ProjectA launches ProjectB attach the debugger then hit enter to continue.

Comment: You need to write unit tests that mock out the inter-process communication.  Then, all you have left to do is prove that the communication itself is working.

Comment: @Darryl Braaten, Me and also the whole team wants to automate that rather than attach debugger manually every time.

Answer (score 1):

The Visual Studio team has released a Visual Studio extension that allows automatically attaching child processes to the current debugger: [Introducing the Child Process Debugging Power Tool](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/11/24/introducing-the-child-process-debugging-power-tool.aspx).

So you can start your `ProjectB` from `ProjectA` with `Process.Start` and it will automatically attach the debugger to this second process.

It is available on the [Gallery](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a1141bff-463f-465f-9b6d-d29b7b503d7a) for Visual Studio 2013 and above.

You can also check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32125477/541420) for how to attach the *current* debugger to any process you may start. Note that it would not be as immediate as the Visual Studio extension since the debugger would be attached *after* the process has started.

Answer (score 0):

You can always manually right click-debug the second project after the first project has started- both will end when the debugger stops.

Answer (score 0):

These options

1. Create a unit test which mimics the test scenario given.
2. Create project C which either references the projects or includes the target CS files as `linked files` (`Add Existing Item` -> `Add` (select drop down `add as link`)) and replicate the process needed to be tested.