# I'm getting strange error during debugging in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, wcf, debugging

[image: debug error]

When I debug my web apps and WCF srvices I often get such error. This happens randomly (I suppose). But after that - I must to start debugging anew from beginning.

PS. Script debugging in IE is disabled.

PPS. Google searching didn't help me.

Comment: if you get useful information from user5434084's reply, would you please mark it as the answer, so it could also help other community members who meet the same issue to research and find the answer easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try setting your executable project as a start up project (in case of multiple projects in the solution)?

*Editing to add the solution that solved the problem mentioned in the comments already:*

If you want to run the projects simultaneously, you can use the "Start multiple projects" option in VS. Goto Solution Explorer -> solution properties -> Common properties -> Startup Project and select Multiple startup projects

But, if your projects are dependent on each other and you want to use same debugger, you might want to consider this solution: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32132756/5434084

Comment: I'm starting several projects simultaneously in my solution.

Comment: If you want to run the projects simultaneously, you can use the "Start multiple projects" option in VS. Goto Solution Explorer -> solution properties -> Common properties -> Startup Project and select Multiple startup projects

But, if your projects are dependent on each other and you want to use same debugger, you might want to consider this solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/32132756/5434084

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helped me.

Comment: Would be grateful if you upvote the answer if it has solved the problem :)